# Magento Product Sorting for Ink Cartridges

Tags: magento-1.9, product, attributes, product-attribute, sorting

Hopefully somebody may be able to help me with this?

I am trying to change the sort order of products on Magento, it is a website that sells ink cartridges.

The order I want to always displays products is as follows:

MultiPack
Black
Cyan
Magenta (actually wrote magento here initially, going mad!)
Yellow

It is setup as a simple product with an additonal attribute of cartridge colour, I have set default sort order in magento config to cartridge colour but it still displays in order

Black
Cyan
Magenta
Multipack
Yellow

[image: Attribute setup]

[image]

Any help would be greatly received.

Comment: Try giving `0 1 2 3 4`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have tried this but it hasn't helped :(